# App not run properly from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I create app named "onlineContact" that save your contact in cloud and you can access your contacts from any Android phone using login. This app is working fine when I test it. I connect my mobile with computer and run it from android studio it's good. So, I upload this app on Google Play Store but When I download and install app from play store it's not worked. What's the problem with this.

Here is my app link on Play store [onlineContact](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azeem.onlinecontact)
Install it click on any link like login, create account or forget password.
When you clicked any of them it's crashed.

I tried it again from android studio and install it and it's working fine. Now how can I checked what the problem with this. I'm not able to place all code of my app here. Please help me about this what i can do.

**Bulid.gradil(Modual:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.azeem.onlinecontact"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',        {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

protected void login(View view){
    EditText etxtPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtPhoneNumber);
    EditText etxtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxtPassword);
    String phoneNumber = etxtPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
    String password = etxtPassword.getText().toString();
    String action = "login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(action, phoneNumber, password);
}


protected void forgetPassActivity(View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ForgetPassword.class));
}

protected void createAccount(View view){
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, CreateAccount.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}

}
```

This activity open fine when I run app But it not work any further when I clicked on any button it will crashed.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @MikeM. I have nothing new. In my previous question no one answer. Can you please take a look at this.

Comment: In 14 hours, you've done nothing to try to solve this yourself?

Comment: Because it's working fine when I run it from android studio. Then how I know the problem ?

Comment: @MikeM. Definitely I solved it if I found any error but there is no error, I new in android first time I publish app on play store